# find the smallest number in a list

Tags: algorithm, performance, divide-and-conquer

I'm trying to find the smallest number in a list. The numbers in the list could be:

```
   1. decrease first and then increase (won't decrease again)
           [5,3,2,0,1,6,99]

   2. or increase only
           [3,4,5,6,7,8]

   3. or decrease only
           [8,6,4,3,2]
```

The numbers are greater than or equal to 0

The only thing that I can use is to compare the current number with its previous number and the next number. But it is too slow. Is there any method in O(logN) or even faster?

Comment: Are you guaranteed that the orders you listed are the only ones that can be presented?  If you can't guarantee order then O(n) is the best you can do.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, I can guarantee that there are only three conditions of the order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon problem constraints, case-2 and case-3 of either increasing or decreasing sequence can be found just by comparing beginning or ending two elements of the sequence in O(1) time complexity.

Now, for the case first having property of first decreasing and increasing can be found in O(logN) time complexity, where N is length of sequence.

If we analyze, sequence which will look like following:

```
\           /
 \         /
 (x)     (y)
   \     /
    \   /
    (ans)
```

So, while performing binary search, In each step we will partition our range of search to half and move to either of one half based on location of element.
If middle element exists in first deceasing part like as `x` we can move to right side and if middle element exists in second increasing part like as `y` we can move to left side. In this way we move towards proximity of answer `ans`.

Since in each step, we are dividing search range by half and moving towards one half, the complexity of the solution become O(logN).

The sample code in c++ looks like below:

```
int findSmallest(vector<int>ar) {
   int n = ar.size();
   if (n == 1) return ar[0];
   if (ar[1] > ar[0]) return ar[0]; //Increase only condition
   if (ar[n - 1] < ar[n - 2]) return ar[n - 1]; // Decrease only condition
   int lo = 1, hi = n - 2;
   int ans;
   while (lo <= hi) {
      int mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
      if ((ar[mid] < ar[mid - 1]) && (ar[mid] < ar[mid + 1])) {
        ans = ar[mid];
        break;
      }
      if ((ar[mid] < ar[mid - 1]) && (ar[mid] > ar[mid + 1])) { //have to move right
         lo = mid + 1;
      } else {
        hi = mid - 1;
      }
   }
   return ans;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but in some cases that is not working:
[13,6,4,4,3,6]

Comment: Above algorithm works considering that we will not have multiple occurrence of same element consecutively. Your examples and statement was not obvious to understand that there could be multiple occurrence of same element. Sorry for that. Still, I'm not sure but problem may have constraints like for each increasing/decreasing sequence elements are distinct.

Answer (score 3):

A variation of a bisection still works, with the logarithmic complexity.

- Test the first two numbers. If they are increasing, you are done.
- Test the last two numbers. If they are decreasing, you are done.
- Otherwise, the left side of the range is on a decreasing slope, and the right on the increasing. Bisect, and select the half with the same property. Keep going until the range collapses to 1 element.

Comment: Yes, that's the general idea. But *"select the half with the same property"* is a little over-simplified. There might not be a half with the same property.

Comment: @user3386109 Only if you hit a minimum. Of course, I didn't spell out the termination condition perfectly.